# Show stringified json in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, json, html, contenteditable, stringify

I was using textarea to display the json in string format, for that I used this

```
JSON.stringify(this, null, '\t')
```

To solve some issue in textarea positioning I decided to use contenteditable div. How to show json in contenteditable div as

```
BusinessUnit : {
    "title": "Business Unit",
    "type": "Text",
    "options": "",
    "required": true,
    "defaultValue": "1",
    "tooltip": "This is a Business-unit",
    "unique": true
}
```

rather than as a showing it as string

```
BusinessUnit : { "title": "Business Unit", "type": "Text", "options": "", "required": true, "defaultValue": "1", "tooltip": "This is a Business-unit", "unique": true }
```

Comment: You'd have to somehow parse it, split it, add tags and breaks etc.

Comment: @adeneo do i have to do it by custom code?

Comment: no just use     jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_OBJEXT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to either use a contenteditable `<pre>` element instead of a `<div>`, or add `white-space: pre` to the `<div>`'s CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3DKLW/

Answer (score 2):

if u have a string Json that name BusinessUnit , u can parse it ilke below

```
                Obj_BusinessUnit= jQuery.parseJSON(BusinessUnit);
            var Unique=Obj_BusinessUnit.unique
            var Title=Obj_BusinessUnit.title
```

and so on for the rest of the Properties this is in JAvascript
in C# u have to use

```
                JavaScriptSerializer Js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Channel_info=Js.Deserialize<class>(Json string of the class);
            Js.Serialize( an object oa a class to Json String)
```

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer namespase is System.Web.Script.Serialization

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is built-in to the standard JSON library.  All you need to do is:

```
formatJSON: function(jString) {
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jString), null, 2);
}
```

It won't unwrap the root property though - that is, your example would be shown like this (note the leading curly brace and the quotes around BusinessUnit):

```
{ 
    "BusinessUnit" : {
        "title": "Business Unit",
        "type": "Text",
        "options": "",
        "required": true,
        "defaultValue": "1",
        "tooltip": "This is a Business-unit",
        "unique": true
    }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
json = {
    "title": "Business Unit",
    "type": "Text",
    "options": "",
    "required": true,
    "defaultValue": "1",
    "tooltip": "This is a Business-unit",
    "unique": true
}
for(var key in json){
    $('div').append(key + " : " + json[key] + "<br/>"); 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuuNW/)

Or you could do it like this

```
var p = JSON.stringify(json);
$('div').append(p.replace(/,/g,',<br/>').replace(/{/g,"{<br/>").replace(/}/g,"<br/>}"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuuNW/1/)